# Error 500 In htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, phalcon

I am trying to learning phalcon php, but it return error 500 when i try to use the htaccess from tutorial

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html

Comment: Check your Apache `error.log` for the reason why 500 is coming.

Comment: Sometimes this kind of problem occurs when sending the file on the ftp server in binary mode, not text mode ... (lot of ftp applications don't know .htaccess files)